# Correct way to use monocolor unicode emojis?

Tags: css, unicode, fonts, emoji

I use unicode emoji icons on my website as they are very convenient (in particular regarding database storage).

The thing is they are rendered differently by each client. I particularly dislike some coloured emojis, as they don't integrate well in my website's minimalistic design.

I see there are fonts around that provide a quite complete set of monochrome emoji characters : Symbola, DejaVu, Noto-Emoji. But I found only partial and confused information about how to use them.

Since it's quite hard to test (rendering very dependent on browser / platform), I'd love to know if I came up with a good solution.

To be clear, the goal is to use the Noto-Emoji font ONLY for the emojis. For the rest, I'd like to use the font defined by other parts of my css.

Here's what I came up with :

1. Download NotoEmoji from https://www.google.com/get/noto/
2. Add this to my css :

   @font-face {
       font-family: 'NotoEmoji-Regular';
       src: url('NotoEmoji-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
       unicode-range: U+1F300-1F5FF, U+1F600-1F64F, U+1F680-1F6FF, U+2600-26FF;
   }
   body{
       font-family:"NotoEmoji-Regular";
   }

Is this this a correct way to achieve what I'm trying to do ? I'm a bit doubtful since it seems quite easy and very useful, yet I didn't find a complete example of it online.

These are my concerns :

- This seems to work well on my setup (Chrome, Windows 10). How compatible is this with other setups ?
- Isn't there a cdn hosting the font ? The font is around 400kb, so it would be great if it wasn't downloaded for my site only

Thanks !!

---

edit :

Testing with the following code, it works well on my desktop (all icons are red and have a consistent style). On my phone (android 6), "eye" and "tool" aren't red. All the other icons work well.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'NotoEmoji-Regular';
                src: url('NotoEmoji-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
                unicode-range: U+1F300-1F5FF, U+1F600-1F64F, U+1F680-1F6FF, U+2600-26FF;
            }
            body{
                font-family: "NotoEmoji-Regular", "Roboto", sans-serif !important;
                color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     Chain <br/>
    ◉ Dot <br/>
     Group <br/>
     Person <br/>
     Folder <br/>
     Eye <br/>
     Scroll <br/>
     Tools <br/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it's a Google font, you can use it directly from Google's site instead of copying it to your own. That I know for sure. I don't have answers for your other concerns right now; would have to do some testing first. Are you sure the "eye" and "tools" emojis are 1) present in the font, and 2) in the unicode-ranges provided?